# Pointing route 53 dns to wordpress site in AWS ec2

Tags: amazon

I need help with WordPress site on EC2 which I have pointed to route 53 DNS name. I am able to access the Wordpress site through the new DNS but other links are still going with the instance name. Can you please help me with how to convert all the links to the new domain name.

For example:

EC2 Wordpress site: http://ec123-3-54-45-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Domain name: myblog.com

I have already pointed my myblog.com(route 53) to Wordpress site(http://ec123-3-54-45-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) and it works fine.

I am able to see the site with a new URL.

But when I click on any of the blog links on my site it points to EC2 URL(http://ec123-3-54-45-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) and shows the ec2 URL on the browser instead of myblog.com URL.

Please help to resolve these issues.

Comment: Can you check which URLs you've configured under Settings, General? That's what WordPress uses as the basis for URLs it generates itself. I'd guess you've put the EC2 URLs there.

Comment: @Rup is right, you need to go to your dashboard and under Settings | General change the URL. Then refresh your browser caches and reload the site in your browser and it should work as expected. If you have hard coded the old URL into any config files you will need to change those too.

Comment: Sure that worked for me, thanks!